# WSO2ESB Force endpoint to start in a disabled state?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to force an endpoint to start in a disabled state?

It seems any time the application is restarted the Endpoints all start enabled, which for the most part would be the  appropriate state; however we have some endpoints which we only use to forward messages to development in their raw form and having these enabled at all times creates quite a bit of overhead.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You can not disable Endpoint and start it. Nevertheless, You can make use of schedule message processor and expose your Endpoint via it. Note that [forwarding message processor](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Message+Forwarding+Processor) can be enabled and disabled.